# How could I modify my .htaccess to make it work as I want?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is my current .htaccess. It's to make my MVC framework work (www.domain.com/controller/method).

I need to have link like this: www.domain.com/userName.

How (if it's even possible) do I need to modify htaccess folder to make that happen? Because I really don't want to have links like: www.domain.com/controller/method/userName

Comment: What does the PHP look like? What framework are you using? It seems like you would need to change how your FVC (Front View Controller) handles the URL's that the RewriteEngine passes to it.

Comment: Probably you need to setup custom routes to your framework, not related to htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Just explode your ?url param see if the first string is userName and handle it properly. Also consider implementing userName as a core-level controller. That would keep everything much more structured

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CodeIgniter then set this up as a route under config/routes. What framework are you using?